# Visual Studio UnityScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unity3d

Здравствуйте.

На днях начал изучать **ECMAScript**, он же **JavaScript**, он же **UnityScript**.
И для работы с ним, мне необходима поддержка данного языка в **Visual Studio**. Так как **UnityScript** сильно отличен от **ECMAScirpt**, ошибки отображаются ещё с первой строки или с объявления переменной.

Хотелось бы решить эту проблему, всё таки хочется работать с данным ЯП в хорошем IDE.

Comment: Не "он же". Иначе вы могли бы просто включить режим JS, и всё бы работало. А в Unity3D даже его разработчики рекомендуют использовать C#, недостатка в хороших IDE для которого из-за OmniSharp нету :)

Comment: Согласен, но в моём случае, хочется использовать Visual Studio для данного ЯП.
Сам я пишу на C#, но на данный момент в качестве дополнения своих знаний, мне необходимо изучить UnityScript.

Visual Studio Tools for Unity не представляют возможность писать на UnityScript в Visual Studio к сожалению. Может у кого есть опыт работы с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю Visual Studio ***НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТ И НЕ БУДЕТ ПОДДЕРЖИВАТЬ*** JavaScript

Для "нормального" использование JavaScript есть [MonoDevelop](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1087722/getting-back-to-monodevelop-ide-from-visual-studio.html).

Comment: MonoDevelop не лучший вариант в плане удобства и производительности.
У VS есть некоторая поддержка js. Может открыть .js файлы и так далее.

Comment: Файлы может открыть и блокнот… MonoDevelop был в unity изначально. Только потом (когда C# стал очень популярным) разработчики движка интегрировали VS.

Comment: Какая же разница в производительности скриптов написанных на одном "блокноте" и на другом по сути таком же  "блокноте" толко с немного другим функционалом ?

Comment: Есть WebStorm (про интеграцию с unity не знаю) http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Скорость работу у данных утилит разная, функционал тоже.
Мне не совсем удобно работать с таким IDE как MonoDevelop.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/